# Identifying component marked 1050J

Tags: identification, components

Can someone please tell me what this chip or capacitor or 1050J part is?

[image]

Comment: Murata is the component supplier (unless it's a fake). I'd look for the data sheet for the IC above it for major clues. If you have a data sheet link then please provide it.

Comment: What the device is, some RF device?

Comment: "where can I acquire" makes this a shopping question, which isn't allowed. If you remove that, then it's just a part identification question, which *is* allowed, so I suggest removing that.

Answer (score 3):

I'ts a Murata CERALOCK ceramic resonator.

Exact specs for it cannot be determined from the markings, and you need a part ordered with exact same specs for it to run in the environment of that board.

Likely any part you order may have different specs from what you need and the part will not properly work in that circuit.

Comment: Thanks guys!  If anyone knows where I can learn more about it I'd be forever in your debt, or just forever in debt period.